# jenkins selenium webdriver with testng not working

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, testng

I am trying to run simple seleniumhq (version:24.8.0) webdriver test, getting a page clicking some basic things, fill out forms, nothing fancy. It works from eclipse and command line also as a fat-jar from an integration maven project with dependencies too without any error. However when I am trying to execute it from jenkins as a batch command, it starts the suite but fails on the second page after the login page crying for the good old NoSuchElementException on a menu item.

I found other posts on Stackoverflow about this problem mentioning the selenium grid plugin for jenkins but I don't think for running a simple testng.jar needs such an overhead for this task (or correct me if jenkins is unable to do this alone).

Headless mode also not acceptable because we want to test the real UI with lot of javascripts on it and as I read about that different browsers implement it differently.

Other posts says running jenkins as a service is the problem or running it without admin credentials. Is it possible to do this without any monster plugin?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to run Jenkins by using this command java -jar jenkins.war

Comment: I will try it but what is the explanation behind it?

Comment: Because by default, service is not allowed to interact with desktop in Windows. That's why you can't see web browser's UI. It also leads to NoSuchElementException in some cases. So you have to run it from command line.